# What questions lead to different representative statistics?

Tags: optimization, means, descriptive-statistics

What are the questions that are asked whose answer yields the geometric and harmonic means.

For example, we arrive at the arithmetic mean by solving:

$$ \min_y  \sum_{x \in S} (x - y)^2$$

What question, or meaningful optimization problem, have the geometric and harmonic means as their solution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Anti-reflective_coatings